# Is there a way to combine adding elements to a stack?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here I am adding child elements to a stack:

```
        s.Children.Add(
            new Label() { Text1 = "ABC" }
            );
        s.Children.Add(
            new Label() { Text1 = "ABC" }
        );
```

Is there any way I can combine these two rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only `Add` one at a time, but you can initialize with more than one

```
Children = {
  new Label {Text = "Hello World!"},
  new Button {Text = "Click Me!"}
}
```